# Simple C Program is not getting printed

Tags: c, printf, return-value

I am trying to run this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int faculty(int n){
        int i = 1;
        int res = 1;
        for (i = 2;i<= n;i++){
            res = res * i;
        }
        printf("the value is %d\n",res);
        return(0);   
    }
}
```

But somehow there is no result showing up. Could you please explain me how it should be implemented properly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do know that nested functions is not allowed in *standard C*?

Comment: You define a function `faculty` inside `main`(which isn't standard C, but a gcc extension). Now you have a function, but to execute it, you must also call it: `faculty(n);`

Comment: What you're doing here is declaring a function inside your main. You're not calling it. Hoist the declaration of `faculty` outside of main, and call it in main as `faculty(n);`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Comment: Your title says the question is about the return value. But the question actually asks why nothing is printed. Which part are you really asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

#include

```
int faculty( int n )
{
  int i = 1;
  int res = 1;
  for ( i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
  {
    res = res * i;
  }
  printf( "the value is %d\n", res );
  getchar(  );
  return ( 0 );
}

int main(  )
{
  int n = 3;
  printf( "Enter your number: " );
  scanf( " %d", &n );
  faculty( n );
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting from faculty() but it prints something on low numbers.